# Subrepresentations of the tensor square

Tags: representation-theory, tensor-products

I've been reading Serre's Book on Representation Theory, and in chapter 1.6 he introduces us to the symmetric space and alternating space. In the algebra course I did we covered tensor products, and we didn't talk about these two subspaces, so i'm having some doubts about them.

He starts by introducing an automorphism of $V \otimes  V$ : 
$$\theta(x\otimes y) = y \otimes x .$$ Then the space decomposes into $$\operatorname{Sym}^2(V) \oplus \operatorname{Alt}^2(V)$$ somehow; I don't really see where he gets this from the automorphism. Then he claims that $\operatorname{Sym}^2(V)$ has dimension $n(n+1)/2$ and that $\operatorname{Alt}^2(V)$ has dimension $n(n-1)/2$ when $V$ has dimension $n$. I don't really get where this comes from either so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $\theta^2 = 1$, $\theta$ is diagonalizable, and its possible eigenvalues are $\pm 1$. By construction (or by definition, if we like) $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V$ and $\operatorname{Alt}^2 V$ are respectively the $(+1)$- and $(-1)$-eigenspaces of $\theta$, and so $$V \otimes V = \operatorname{Sym}^2 V \oplus \operatorname{Alt}^2 V$$ as claimed.

> **Additional hint** The projections onto each eigenspace are \begin{aligned}\operatorname{Sym} : &V \otimes V \to \operatorname{Sym}^2 V, & \quad & A \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(A + \theta(A)) \\ \operatorname{Alt} : &V \otimes V \to \operatorname{Alt}^2 V, &\quad & A \mapsto \frac{1}{2}(A - \theta(A)) .\end{aligned} To compute the dimensions of the eigenspaces, fix a basis $(E_a)$ of $V$ and compute the image of the induced basis $(E_a \otimes E_b)$ of $V \otimes V$ under each of the maps. Then, for example, $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V = \operatorname{Sym}(V \otimes V)$ is spanned by $\operatorname{Sym}(E_a \otimes E_b) = \frac{1}{2} (E_a \otimes E_b + E_b \otimes E_a)$, and so the set $$\{\frac{1}{2} (E_a \otimes E_b + E_b \otimes E_a) : a \leq b\}$$ spans $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V$. It is linearly independent, so if $V$ has finite dimension, say, $n$, the dimension of $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V$ is the number of pairs $(a, b)$ of integers satisfying $1 \leq a \leq b \leq n$, and there are $\frac{1}{2} n (n - 1)$ of these. Of course, once you know the dimension of on of $\operatorname{Sym}^2 V$ and $\operatorname{Alt}^2 V$ you know the other, since $$\dim \operatorname{Sym}^2 V + \operatorname{Alt}^2 V = \dim (\operatorname{Sym}^2 V \oplus \operatorname{Alt}^2 V) = \dim(V \otimes V) = (\dim V)^2 = n^2 .$$

Answer (score 2):

Think in terms of spaces of matrices. The space of $n\times n$ matrices is of dimension $n^2$ and represents $V\otimes V$. The automorphism introduced is equal to the matrix transpose. The subspace fixed by the automorphism is the space of symmetric matrices. Since a symmetric matrix is uniquely determined by its values on and above the diagonal, it has dimension $\binom{n+1}{2}$ (since that is the number of such entries). Any matrix can be uniquely decomposed as the sum of a symmetric matrix and an antisymmetric matrix, and the antisymmetric matrices have dimension $\binom{n}{2}$ since they are uniquely determined by the entries *above* the diagonal (the diagonal being equal to $0$).